# Implementing vue.js router guards when user infos come from asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, promise, vue-router

I'm working on a Vue.js application and I need to implement router guards to limit access based on user role and prevent an unlogged user to access the application.
The login process involves an external application (WSO2 Identity Server, specifically), and the user info retrieved are saved in a Vuex store.
The problem is that the login function is asynchronous, therefore when the router guards are executed user infos aren't available yet. To make it work I called the login function inside an anonymous async function and I put the guards inside its `then` block.
Since I didn't find examples of this approach on the internet, I would like to know if it is correct or there is a better way of handling this problem. Thank you all in advance.

Here's an example of my router code:

```
... router code

(async function() {
  // get user data and saves them in the vuex store
  await userService.initUserData();
})().then( function() {
    const isAuthenticated = store.getters.getIsAuthenticated;
    const userRole = store.getters.getUserRole;

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      // check if user is logged in,
      // if not redirect to login page (LoginPage)
      if (to.name !== 'LoginPage' && !isAuthenticated) {
        next({ name: 'LoginPage' });
      } else {
        if (to.meta.customerAuth) {
          if (userRole === 'Customer') {
            next();
          } else if (userRole === 'Admin') {
            next({ name: 'AdminView' });
          } else {
            next({ name: 'LoginPage' });
          }
        } else if (to.meta.adminAuth) {
          if (userRole === 'Admin') {
            next();
          } else if (userRole === 'Customer') {
            next({ name: 'CustomerView' });
          } else {
            next({ name: 'LoginPage' });
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should persist your user informations in the localstorage so you don't need to fetch permissions everytime you refresh the page.

What you can do if permissions would happen to change for the validity of a token is to return a 401 HTTP code that would logout and redirect to login to get a new token with the new permissions.

As you store your user infos in storage you don't need to wait to configure your guards.

The point is: login should only happen once, if you refresh you shouldn't have to login again

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The refresh issue is something I'm planning to solve later, now my main concern is about the correctness of the "guards-inside-then block" approach. User infos are already being saved in a vuex store, but still I have to wait they are available before I can run the guards. Maybe the problem is that the login function is called inside the router (whereas it should be called earlier), but I'm new to Vue.js and I don't know how to do it better. I would like an advice concerning that point.

Comment: What you could do is login in `main.js`, then mount your app once the login is finished. `login().then(() => app.mount('#app'));`

Comment: I wasn't able to apply this solution 'cause the way the login happens in my application is a bit complicated and I couldn't do it in the main file. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry if I bother you again, but I was thinking about your idea and I wonder: how can I do the login in `main.js` if I need to get user's credentials first? At the moment, things go like this: when the user enters the application, it shows a welcome page with a button. Clicking the button redirects the browser to the WSO2 Identity Server login page, where the user enters her/his credentials. Finally, in the router, it is called `UserService` which gets all user's data and access token from WSO2 and saves them in a vuex persisted store. So, how can I do all these things in `main.js`?

Comment: You can think of another service responsible for just the login. Do a separate app or plain HTML, for your case, plain HTML is sufficient. The HTML login page will try to login, and your server will return a 3xx (redirect) to your app with your token in the URL as a GET parameter for example. I don't know how safe that is though, you'll need to check

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, this plain HTML page should substitute the welcome page I mentioned in my comment, and redirect the user to the WSO2 login page, shouldn't it? Without any offence, and thanking you again for your help, this solution seems a bit contorted to me. Isn't there a way of achieving this without using a separate app/website? After all, I think this is quite a common problem, so there should be kinds of best practices to face it.

Comment: What's contorted here is the way you try to login, so complex A issue, in your case means complex B solution. You can do this the way you want actually, you could have another html file in your public folder, however you'll need to adjust your webserver routing options to enable rendering the other html page. Iwas just suggesting here a way to have a login form by dodging the main app that requires auth at root level before even mounting the vue app

Comment: I understand. Could you please suggest a more linear way of doing the login, in order to avoid the need for a complex solution and having working router guards? I'd like to learn best practices.